# Bigquery: "Not enough memory"

Tags: google-bigquery

Bigquery started to give me error:not enough memory when I run this query this morning. The two tables involved contain no more than 5GB data. Plus I'm using table decorators, 1407249067530 equals around 10:30am today(20140805). I wonder what's the problem.

Job ID: red-road-574:job_x8flLfo4QwA1gQ_FCrNWbKY-bZM

```
  select * from 
                (                           
                select  t_connection.row_id AS debug_row_id,                        
                    t_connection.hardware_id AS hardware_id,                        
                    t_connection.debug_data AS debug_data,                      
                    t_connection.connection_status AS connection_status,                        
                    t_connection.date_time AS debug_date_time,                      
                    t_gps.hardware_id AS hardware_id2,                      
                    t_gps.latitude AS latitude,                     
                    t_gps.longitude AS longitude,                       
                    t_gps.date_time AS gps_date_time,                       
                     t_gps.zip_code AS zip_code,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY debug_row_id ORDER BY time_diff) row_num,                       
                    from(                           
                          select    *,                      
                                ABS(t_gps.date_time-t_connection.date_time) AS time_diff                    
                              from ( select CONCAT(String(gg.hardware_id),String(gg.date_time)) as row_id,                      
                                    gg.hardware_id as hardware_id,              
                                    gg.latitude as latitude,                
                                    gg.longitude as longitude,              
                                    gg.date_time as date_time,              
                                     gg.zip_code as zip_code                        
                                     from   [my data set.table1_20140805@1407249067530-] gg                         

                                   ) AS t_gps                           

                                    INNER JOIN EACH                     

                                  ( select  CONCAT(CONCAT(String(dd.debug_reason),String(dd.hardware_id)),String(dd.date_time)) as row_id,                      
                                        dd.hardware_id as hardware_id,                  
                                        dd.date_time as date_time,                      
                                        dd.debug_data as debug_data,                    
                                case                    
                                    when dd.debug_reason = 1 then 'Successful_Connection'               
                                    when dd.debug_reason = 2 then 'Dropped_Connection'              
                                    when dd.debug_reason = 3 then 'Failed_Connection'               
                                end AS connection_status                                                
                                    from    [my data set.table2_20140805@1407249067530-] dd         
                                    where   dd.debug_reason in (50013, 50017, 50018)    

                                ) as t_connection                           

                                 ON t_connection.hardware_id = t_gps.hardware_id                    
                )                           
               )  WHERE row_num=1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is running on Google Bigquery, why indexing matters? And I actually don't own the memory...

Comment: Well, you're going to have to simplify it.  Who owns the memory is not relevant.  Looks like SQL to me; indexing is always relevant, if you have joins.

Comment: Do you have a job id from a failure?

Comment: red-road-574:job_x8flLfo4QwA1gQ_FCrNWbKY-bZM  is my last try:)

Comment: Split into smaller query and compare speed

Comment: Jordan Tigani, did you find something?

Answer (score 2):

You're hitting an odd corner case. When you use `allowLargeResults` with results that are nested or repeated and you don't use `flattenResults=false`, the query goes into a special mode. (when you use timestamps, you're really using a nested data structure, which was a design decision that spawned 1000 bugs and is hopefully changing soon). This special query mode has some limitations, which are what you're hitting.

In general, we want this to be seamless, which is why it isn't documented. However, since you're running into a problem here, I'll explain a little about about how to avoid it.

You have a couple of options to get around this:

1. If you're using nested or repeated results (it looks like you're not, which is good):

   - rename your results without dots in the name.
   - set the flattenResults field on the query to 'false'. This means that nested and repeated fields will be actually nested and repeated in the results.
2. If you're using timestamps in the results:

   - Convert your timestamps to strings or numeric values. Sorry.
3. If you don't really need large results:

   - unset the allowLargeResults flag.

I realize that all of these options are deeply unsatisfying. This is an area we're actively working to improve.

Comment: I'll tweak my query to see what will happen. While waiting for you, I tried this:
1. do sub-query (basically the same sql but without the last step's select) and store result into a table, saying table1
2. select * table1 where row_num=1   it failed every time, one job id was job_JXUiRlXP-jOxolrCQ-wUA9PK-Uw, But, it was sucess every time as I tried select * table1 where row_num=10 (or where clause on other fields)

Comment: By "with results that are nested or repeated", does it includes intermediate results as in my nested sub queries? I have TIMESTAMP data (date_time) in both nested queries and final results, does it fit into the case 1 also?

Answer (score 0):

Now with allowLargeReults=true and flattenResults=false and convert timestamps to numeric value at the first step

```
  select * from 
                (                           
                select  row_id AS debug_row_id,                     
                    hardware_id AS hardware_id,                     
                    debug_data AS debug_data,                       
                    connection_status AS connection_status,                     
                    date_time AS debug_date_time,                       
                    hardware_id2 AS hardware_id2,                       
                    latitude AS latitude,                       
                    longitude AS longitude,                     
                    date_time2 AS gps_date_time,                        
                    zip_code AS zip_code,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY debug_row_id ORDER BY time_diff) row_num,                       
                    from(                           
                          select    *,                      
                                ABS(t_gps.date_time2-t_connection.date_time) AS time_diff                   
                              from ( select CONCAT(String(gg.hardware_id),String(gg.date_time)) as row_id_gps,                      
                                    gg.hardware_id as hardware_id2,                 
                                    gg.latitude as latitude,                
                                    gg.longitude as longitude,              
                                    TIMESTAMP_TO_MSEC(gg.date_time) as date_time2,              
                                     gg.zip_code as zip_code                        
                                     from   [test.gps32_20140805@1407249067530-] gg                         

                                   ) AS t_gps                           

                                    INNER JOIN EACH                     

                                  ( select  CONCAT(CONCAT(String(dd.debug_reason),String(dd.hardware_id)),String(dd.date_time)) as row_id,                      
                                        dd.hardware_id as hardware_id,                  
                                        TIMESTAMP_TO_MSEC(dd.date_time) as date_time,                       
                                        dd.debug_data as debug_data,                    
                                case                    
                                    when dd.debug_reason = 1 then 'Successful_Connection'               
                                    when dd.debug_reason = 2 then 'Dropped_Connection'              
                                    when dd.debug_reason = 3 then 'Failed_Connection'               
                                end AS connection_status                                                
                                    from    [test.debug_data_developer_20140805@1407249067530-] dd      
                                    where   dd.debug_reason in (50013, 50017, 50018)

                                ) as t_connection                           

                                 ON t_connection.hardware_id = t_gps.hardware_id2                   
                )                           
               )  WHERE row_num=1
```

it gives me

```
Query Failed
Error: Resources exceeded during query execution.
Job ID: red-road-574:job_ikWQvffmPEUP6DtTvJaYpXHFJ2M
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the functioning SQL with allowLargeResults=true, flattenResults=true. I don't know what I did to make this work, maybe only add a HAVING clause? But in the JOIN, I change one side to be a whole table instead of the one with decorator as above, so the data involved actually increased. I'm not sure whether it can keep successful or it's just temporary luck.
[image]